# How do orthodox Hindus interpret these Vedic mantras that seem to suggest that the Rishis authored the mantras?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, purva-mimamsa, apaurusheyatva

It has been asserted that these mantras suggest that the Rishis authored the Vedic mantras:

> RV 1.61.4: asmā idu stomaṃ saṃ hinomi rathaṃ na taṣṭeva — “For him, I
> design this hymn, just as a carpenter designs a chariot”
>
> RV 1.77.1: kathā dāśemāgnaye kāsmai devajuṣṭocyate bhāmine gīḥ — “ How
> shall we offer to Agni, what kind of words should we say to him the
> bright one, which will be divinely acceptable?”
>
> RV 1.94.1: imaṃ stomamarhate jātavedase rathamiva saṃ mahemā manīṣayā
> — “This stotra we make for the most sacred Jātaveda with deep
> meditation, just like building a chariot”
>
> RV 1.143.1: pra tavyasīṃ navyasīṃ dhītimagnaye vāco matiṃ sahasaḥ
> sūnave bhare — “I offer this newest and most expansive ritual and
> words to the Son of Strength”
>
> RV 2.19.8: evā te gṛtsamadāḥ śūra manmāvasyavo na vayunāni takṣuḥ —
> “Thus, we Gṛtsamadas have designed these words for you, O Indra, just
> as a pathfinder makes paths”

In particular, this verse seems to strongly suggest that:

> RV 1.61.4: asmā idu stomaṃ saṃ hinomi rathaṃ na taṣṭeva — “For him, I design this hymn, just as a carpenter designs a chariot”

But how do those who believe that the Vedic mantras are unauthored, like the followers of Vedanta and Mimamsa do, interpret these verses?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116275/discussion-on-question-by-ikshvaku-how-do-orthodox-hindus-interpret-these-vedic).

Answer (score 3):

First, your question at the end is not correct. You state "But how do those who believe that the Vedic mantras are unauthored, like the followers of Vedanta and Mimamsa do, interpret these verses?" The followers of Vedanta is another way of saying the followers of the Uttara Mimamsa (or another way of saying it is the followers of Vyasa). I think you are trying to differeniate between the followers of the Purva Mimamsa and the Uttara Mimamsa. Both schools are followers of the Vedas.

Many of the Upanishads end with verses giving the lineage of the specific Upanishad. For instance, the Brhadaranyaka Upanishad (https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad) ends with the following in VI.v.2 -

> Verse 6.5.1:
>
> अथ वंशः । पौतिमाषीपुत्रः कात्यायनीपुत्रात्, कात्यायनीपुत्रो गौतमीपुत्रात्, गौतमीपुत्रो भारद्वाजीपुत्रात्, भारद्वाजीपुत्रः पाराशरीपुत्रात्, पाराशरीपुत्र अउपस्वस्तीपुत्रात्, अउपस्वस्तीपुत्रः पाराशरीपुत्रात्, पाराशरीपुत्रः कात्यायनीपुत्रात्, कात्यायनीपुत्रः कौशिकीपुत्रात्, कौशिकीपुत्र आलम्बीपुत्राच्च वैयाघ्रपदीपुत्राच्च, वैयाघ्रपदीपुत्रः काण्वीपुत्राच्च कापीपुत्राच्च, कापीपुत्रः ॥ १ ॥
>
> atha vaṃśaḥ | pautimāṣīputraḥ kātyāyanīputrāt, kātyāyanīputro gautamīputrāt, gautamīputro bhāradvājīputrāt, bhāradvājīputraḥ pārāśarīputrāt, pārāśarīputra aupasvastīputrāt, aupasvastīputraḥ pārāśarīputrāt, pārāśarīputraḥ kātyāyanīputrāt, kātyāyanīputraḥ kauśikīputrāt, kauśikīputra ālambīputrācca vaiyāghrapadīputrācca, vaiyāghrapadīputraḥ kāṇvīputrācca kāpīputrācca, kāpīputraḥ || 1 ||
>
> 1. Now the line of teachers: The son of Pautimāṣī (received it) from the son of Kātyāyanī. He from the son of Gautamī. The son of Gautamī from the son of Bhāradvājī. He from the son of Pārāśarī. The son of Pārāśarī from the son of Aupasvastī. He from the son of another Pārāśarī. He from the son of Kātyāyanī. The son of Kātyāyanī from the son of Kauśikī. The son of Kauśikī from the son of Ālambī and the son of Vaiyāghrapadī. The son of Vaiyāghrapadī from the son of Kāṇvī and the son of Kāpī. The son of Kāpī—
>
> Verse 6.5.2:
>
> आत्रेयीपुत्रात्, आत्रेयीपुत्रो गौतमीपुत्रात्, गौतमीपुत्रो भारद्वाजीपुत्रात्, भारद्वाजीपुत्रः पाराशरीपुत्रात्, पाराशरीपुत्रो वात्सीपुत्रात्, वात्सीपुत्रः पाराशरीपुत्रात्, पाराशरीपुत्रो वार्कारुणीपुत्रात्, वार्कारुणीपुत्रो वार्कारुणीपुत्रात्, वार्कारुणीपुत्र आर्तभागीपुत्रात्, आर्तभागीपुत्रः शौङ्गीपुत्रात्, शौङ्गीपुत्रः साङ्कृतीपुत्रात्, साङ्कृतीपुत्र आलम्बायनीपुत्रात्, आलम्बायनीपुत्र आलम्बीपुत्रात्, आलम्बीपुत्रो जायन्तीपुत्रात्, जायन्तीपुत्रो माण्डूकायनीपुत्रात्, माण्डूकायनीपुत्रो माण्डूकीपुत्रात्, माण्डूकीपुत्रः शाण्डिलीपुत्रात्, शाण्डिलीपुत्रो राथीतरीपुत्रात्, राथीतरीपुत्रो भालुकीपुत्रात्, भालुकीपुत्रः क्रौञ्चिकीपुत्राभ्याम्, क्रौञ्चिकीपुत्रौ वैदभृतीपुत्रात्, वैदभृतीपुत्रः कार्शकेयीपुत्रात्, कार्शकेयीपुत्रः प्राचीनयोगीपुत्रात्, प्राचीनयोगीपुत्रः साञ्जीवीपुत्रात्, साञ्जीवीपुत्रः प्राश्नीपुत्रादासुरिवासिनः, प्राश्नीपुत्र आसुरायणात्, आसुरायण आसुरेः, आसुरिः ॥ २ ॥
>
> ātreyīputrāt, ātreyīputro gautamīputrāt, gautamīputro bhāradvājīputrāt, bhāradvājīputraḥ pārāśarīputrāt, pārāśarīputro vātsīputrāt, vātsīputraḥ pārāśarīputrāt, pārāśarīputro vārkāruṇīputrāt, vārkāruṇīputro vārkāruṇīputrāt, vārkāruṇīputra ārtabhāgīputrāt, ārtabhāgīputraḥ śauṅgīputrāt, śauṅgīputraḥ sāṅkṛtīputrāt, sāṅkṛtīputra ālambāyanīputrāt, ālambāyanīputra ālambīputrāt, ālambīputro jāyantīputrāt, jāyantīputro māṇḍūkāyanīputrāt, māṇḍūkāyanīputro māṇḍūkīputrāt, māṇḍūkīputraḥ śāṇḍilīputrāt, śāṇḍilīputro rāthītarīputrāt, rāthītarīputro bhālukīputrāt, bhālukīputraḥ krauñcikīputrābhyām, krauñcikīputrau vaidabhṛtīputrāt, vaidabhṛtīputraḥ kārśakeyīputrāt, kārśakeyīputraḥ prācīnayogīputrāt, prācīnayogīputraḥ sāñjīvīputrāt, sāñjīvīputraḥ prāśnīputrādāsurivāsinaḥ, prāśnīputra āsurāyaṇāt, āsurāyaṇa āsureḥ, āsuriḥ || 2 ||
>
> 2. From the son of Ātreyī. The son of Ātreyī from the son of Gautamī. The son of Gautamī from the son of Bhāradvājī. He from the son of Pārāśarī-. The son of Pārāśarī from the son of Vātsī. The son of Vātsī from the son of another Pārāśarī. The son of Pārāśarī from the son of Vārkāruṇī. He from the son of another Vārkāruṇī. This one from the son of Ārtabhāgī. He from the son of Śauṅgī. The son of Śauṇgī from the son of Sāṃkṛtī. He from the son of Ālambāyanī. He again from the son of Ālambī. The son of Ālambī from the son of Jāyantī. He from the son of Māṇḍūkāyanī. He in his turn from the son of Māṇḍūkī. The son of Māṇḍūkī from the son of Sāṇḍilī. The son of Śāṇḍilī from the son of Rāthītarī. He from the son of Bhālukī. The son of Bhālukī from the two sons of Krauñcikī. They from the son of Vaidabhṛtī. He from the son of Kārśakeyī. He again from the son of Prācīnayogī. He from the son of Sāṃjīvī. The son of Sāṃjīvī from Āsurivāsin, the son of Prāśnī. The son of Prāśnī from Āsurāyaṇa. He from Āsuri. Āsuri—
>
> Verse 6.5.3:
>
> याज्ञवल्क्यात्, याज्ञवल्क्य ऊद्दालकात्, ऊद्दालकोऽरुणात्, अरुण उपवेशेः, उपवेशिः कुश्रेः, कुश्रिर्वाजश्रवसः, वाजश्रवा जीह्वावतो बाध्योगात्, जीह्वावान्बाध्योगोऽसिताद्वार्षगणात्, असितो वार्षगणो हरितात्कश्यपात्, हरितः कश्यपः शिल्पात्कश्यपात्, शिल्पः कश्यपः कश्यपान्नैध्रुवेः, कश्यपो नैध्रुविर्वाचः, वागम्भिण्याः, अम्भिण्यादित्यात्; आदित्यानीमानि शुक्लानि यजूंषि वाजसनेयेन याज्ञवल्क्येनाख्ययन्ते ॥ ३ ॥
>
> yājñavalkyāt, yājñavalkya ūddālakāt, ūddālako'ruṇāt, aruṇa upaveśeḥ, upaveśiḥ kuśreḥ, kuśrirvājaśravasaḥ, vājaśravā jīhvāvato bādhyogāt, jīhvāvānbādhyogo'sitādvārṣagaṇāt, asito vārṣagaṇo haritātkaśyapāt, haritaḥ kaśyapaḥ śilpātkaśyapāt, śilpaḥ kaśyapaḥ kaśyapānnaidhruveḥ, kaśyapo naidhruvirvācaḥ, vāgambhiṇyāḥ, ambhiṇyādityāt; ādityānīmāni śuklāni yajūṃṣi vājasaneyena yājñavalkyenākhyayante || 3 ||
>
> 3. From Yājñavalkya. Yājñavalkya from Uddālaka. Uddālaka from Aruṇa. Aruṇa from Upaveśi. Upaveśi from Kuśri. Kuśri from Vajaśravas. He from Jihvāvat, the son of Badhyoga. He from Asīta, the son of Varṣagaṇa. He from Harita Kaśyapa. He from Śilpa Kaśyapa. This one from Kaśyapa, the son of Nidhruva. He from Vāc. She from Ambhiṇī. She from the sun. These white Yajuses received from the sun are explained by Yājñavalkya Vājasaneya.
>
> Verse 6.5.4:
>
> समानमा साञ्जीवीपुत्रात्; सञ्जिवीपुत्रो माण्डूकायनेः, माण्डूकायनिर्माण्डव्यात्, माण्डव्यः कौत्सात्, कौत्सो माहित्थेः, माहित्थिर्वामकक्शायणात्, वामकक्शायणः शाण्डिल्यात्, शाण्डिल्यो वात्स्यात्, वात्स्यः कुश्रेः, कुश्रिर्यज्ञवचसो राजस्तम्बायनात्, यज्ञवचा राजस्तम्बायनस्तुरात्कावषेयात्, तुरः कावषेयः प्रजापतेः, प्रजापतिर्ब्रह्मणः, ब्रह्म स्वयंभु; ब्रह्मणे नमः ॥ ४ ॥
> इति पञ्चमं ब्राह्मणम् ॥
> इति षष्ठोऽध्यायः ॥
>
> samānamā sāñjīvīputrāt; sañjivīputro māṇḍūkāyaneḥ, māṇḍūkāyanirmāṇḍavyāt, māṇḍavyaḥ kautsāt, kautso māhittheḥ, māhitthirvāmakakśāyaṇāt, vāmakakśāyaṇaḥ śāṇḍilyāt, śāṇḍilyo vātsyāt, vātsyaḥ kuśreḥ, kuśriryajñavacaso rājastambāyanāt, yajñavacā rājastambāyanasturātkāvaṣeyāt, turaḥ kāvaṣeyaḥ prajāpateḥ, prajāpatirbrahmaṇaḥ, brahma svayaṃbhu; brahmaṇe namaḥ || 4 ||
> iti pañcamaṃ brāhmaṇam ||
> iti ṣaṣṭho'dhyāyaḥ ||
>
> 4. The same up to the son of Sāṃjīvī. The son of Sāṃjīvī from Māṇḍūkāyani. Māṇḍūkāyani from Māṇḍavya. Māṇḍavya from Kautsa. Kautsa from Māhitthi. He from Vāmakakṣāyaṇa. He from Śāṇḍilya. Śāṇḍilya from Vātsya. Vātsya from Kuśri. Kuśri from Yajñavacas, the son of Rājastamba. He from Tura, the son of Kavaṣi. He from Prajāpati (Hiraṇyagarbha). Prajāpati through his relation to Brahman (the Vedas). Brahman is self-born. Salutation to Brahman.
>
> [commentary] Now the line of teachers of the whole Upaniṣad is being given. (They are here named after their mothers) because the wife holds the most important place (in this ceremony).[2] It has been mentioned that a gifted son is born. Hence the Upaniṣad is narrating the line of teachers by describing the son through the name of the mother. These white Yajuses, etc.—‘White’ because they are not mixed up (with human faults), or these Yajuses are pure or fresh. From Prajāpati down to the son of Pautimāṣī is a descending order (if we read it inversely), with the teacher always mentioned first. (The line is) the same up to the son of Sāṃjīvī.[3] Prajāpati through his relation to Brahman or the Vedas. That Brahman (the Vedas) has come down the line from Prajāpati and variously branched off among us. It is without beginning and end—self-horn, or eternal. Salutation to that Brahman (the Vedas). And salutation to the teachers who have followed it.

The explanation is in the vedas themselves.

Comment: This does not address the RV verses from the OP's question though

Comment: Is this yet another critique on OP's question? How about actually answering what is asked in the question? 'The explanation is in the vedas themselves' - what is this supposed to mean? Samhitas or Upanishads? The reader has to figure out on their own?

Comment: I mentioned both purva and uttara mimamsa schools to show how both believe that the vedic words are eternal.